WhatsApp and other messages and contact or profile-based apps: making contacts available to other apps via a service with permissions
In this post, I ask about how to make contacts from Whatsapp available in the Script Rehearsal app.
This post is not limited to WhatsApp but extends to other message and contact or profile-based apps. I am asking for/about Android support to make contacts available to other apps via a service with permissions.
Indeed, it would be nice to be able to export the contact list from an application that made use of contacts with contact information to the device and make it accessible to other apps, via a service, that asks you permission to access the contacts.
Is this at all supported in Android? What apps and web services (Facebook?) support this?
